# Approximation of Poisson random variable with the sum of exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis

I have been working on the following question so far:
Find a sequence of real numbers $a_{n}$ such that the sum $S_{n} := \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{\{\eta_{i} \geq a_{n}\}} \rightarrow\ Poi(1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ where $\eta_{i}$ is an exponential random variable with mean 1.

My idea is as follows: in order to apply Poisson limit theorem, find $a_{n}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(1_{\{\eta_{i} \geq a_{n}\}} = 1) = \dfrac{1}{n}$, which gives off $a_{n} = \text{ln}(n)$ by looking for $a_{n}$ such that $\int_{a_{n}}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = e^{-a_{n}} = \dfrac{1}{n} \iff a_{n} = \text{ln}(n)$. Then, it is clear that $\dfrac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}(1_{\{\eta_{i} \geq a_{n}\}} = 1) = 1$ for any n, which allows us to apply Poisson limit theorem to conclude. However, I think this logic of "discretization" works for any continuous random variable to approximate into Poisson random variable, not specifically exponential random variable, and now I feel a bit suspicious on my logic here.

Could anyone verify the logic and proof here and if it is wrong, could anyone help me to figure out? Thank you so much!